# Sell offline maps as in-app purchases

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, skmaps

I plan to sell offline maps in my app:

http://developer.skobbler.com/#plans

To do this I would like to add two consumable items to iTunes Connect:
 - one small map 
 - one large map

After a purchase it will be possible to download the map until it'll be downloaded successfully. Then map will be marked as "downloaded". If user deleted or reinstalled the app, he'll have to buy the item again. But if app data will be transfered to another phone or restored then purchase will be saved.

How does it fit to AppStore policy? Does anyone have this kind of experience?

Comment: Appstore policy is you need to have a restore facility for your in app purchases, by sound of it thats what you're planning to do so should be fine

Comment: From the point of view of the the SDK provider, each map download will be considered as a "new map" download - you will have to implement the remember/restore logic at app level

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to add the Map feature with inApp purchase than I have some suggestions that you should follow to keep it under the App Store review guidelines & to make sure it gets approved easily without any issues.

**Important Points :**

1. First highlight this as a pro feature. You have 2 different Maps with 2 different inApp purchases. So you can highlight inApp purchase screen with 2 different pro features
2. Second important thing is you have mentioned here you wants to keep it consumable. Which is not possible. You must keep it Non consumable inApp purchase.
3. As per the current rules you will have to add Restore purchases button into inApp purchase screen. So if any user has already purchased can restore it & use it again.

Hope this helps to everyone.